# Remote PowerShell Excution by non admins

Tags: powershell, remoting

I’m having a problem remotely executing scripts as a non administrator on the target server.

This is an portion of the scripts I’m trying to run:

```
New-PSSession -computername ServerA.DomainA.org -Credential $LoginCredentials 
$PSServerA = Get-PSSession -computername bl ServerA.DomainA.org 
Invoke-Command -Session $PSServerA -scriptblock {Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement}
```

I get the following error:

> The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement, C:\Program Files\Quest Software\Management Shell for AD\Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement.Types.ps1xml : File skipped because of the following validation exception: AuthorizationManager check failed..

This is a small part of an account creation script I’m writing. I want the helpdesk to be able to execute the script and they are not members of the administrators group on the target server although they are members of the server operators group. I can logon to the target server as them and from a Standard (non admin) PowerShell  prompt I can successfully run the command the Add-PSSnapin.

The ExecutionPolicy on the target server is Unrestricted.

I have given the users Execute rights to the default microsoft.Powershell remote session configuration, this is successful as they can open the session.

So the question I have is what rights do I need to assign the users in order for them to execute the commands remotely?

Comment: Can you run `Invoke-Command -Session $PSServerA -scriptblock {get-executionpolicy}` to get the effective executionpolicy for the $PSServer session?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into a PowerShell double-hop restriction. PowerShell doesn't like it when you remote into a machine and then try to access another computer from there. I've never used the AD snap-in before, though. This is my best guess.

Any chance you can contact the developer's of your AD snap-in for help?  They might know.